# Prove that the graph of the function $y=\cos x \cos (x+2)-\cos^2(x+1)$ is a straight line passing though

Tags: analytic-geometry

> $(\frac{\pi}{2},-\sin^2 1)$ and parallel to x axis.

I solved the equation and it basically gets reduced to

$$y=-\sin^2 1$$
It’s clearly parallel to the x axis and passes through $-\sin^2 1$, but where does $\frac{\pi}{2}$ come from?

*I know a similar problem has already been asked on this site, but it doesn’t solve my particular query*

Comment: If $y=-\sin^2 1$ for all $x$ then particularly it is for $x=\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\cos a\cos b=\dfrac{1}{2}(\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)).$ Doing so yields $\begin{align}y&= \dfrac{1}{2}(\cos(2x+2)+\cos2)-\dfrac{1}{2}(\cos(2x+2)+\cos0)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}(1-2\sin^2 1 - 1)\\
&=-\sin^2 1.\end{align}$

Hence it passes through the desired point $(\frac\pi2, -\sin^2 1)$